# Как правильно отображать изменяемые данные в реальном времени?

Tags: android

Я хотел бы отображать писать результат инкремента каждую секунду на экране. Вот моя попытка с ошибкой:

```
        val view = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)
        view.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000.toInt())

        view.setOnClickListener {

        }
        val counter = AtomicInteger()
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_button)


        btn.setOnClickListener {
            thread {
                (0..100).forEach { _ ->
                    Thread.sleep(1_000)
                    view.text = counter.getAndIncrement().toString()
                }
            }
        }
```

Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь выполнить изменения интерфейса за пределами ui потока. Думаю вам (как и мне) не хватает понимания многопоточности в android. Я бы в вашем случаи изучил двунаправленный DataBinding и kotlin coroutines. В любом случаи вашу проблему должен решить

```
runOnUiThread { object :Runnable{
                    override fun run() {
                        view.text = counter.getAndIncrement().toString()
                    }
                
}
```

Это можно вызвать внутри вашего `thread {}`. Так же студия должна предложить вам использовать лямбда выражение.